# How to show choices of the question in view using ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm creating an online exam. I want to show the choices for each question in view.when I run the program it has an error "null reference".

This is my `Question` table:

```
public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }//1
    public int ExamId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionTitle { get; set; }
    public decimal Grade { get; set; }

    #region relations
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual IdentityUser IdentityUser { get; set; }
    public Exam exam { get; set; }
    public List<ChoiceQuestionSelection> choiceQuestionSelection { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

This is my choices table:

```
public class ChoiceQuestionSelection
{
    [Key]
    public int ChoiceQuestionSelectionId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Choice { get; set; }
    public bool IsTrue { get; set; }
    public string FeedbackTrue { get; set; }
    public string FeedbackFalse { get; set; }

    #region relations
    public Question question { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

This is my view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="well well-lg">
            <h4>@item.QuestionTitle</h4>
            <h6>@item.Grade </h6>
            <p>
            @if (item.choiceQuestionSelection.Any(q => q.QuestionId == item.QuestionId))
            {
                @foreach (var choice in item.choiceQuestionSelection)
                {
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" 
                     checked="">@choice.Choice
                    </label>
                }
            }
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

This is the action method:

```
public IActionResult ShowQuestions(int id)
{
    return View(_questionService.GetAllQuestions(id));
}
```

This is the method:

```
public List<Question> GetAllQuestions(int examId)
{
    return _context.questions
                   .Where(q => q.ExamId == examId).ToList();
}
```

I have some choices in my choice table for a question but it doesn't show them. What should I write in my query?

Comment: Can you post the action method which loads the data and sends it to the view? These are the likely cause, first you're not including choiceQuestionSelection in your query and since you did not initialize choiceQuestionSelection as an empty list, you get a null reference

Comment: I update my post. yeah Thank's. I should try this way.I didn't include the choice table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load your questions from the database, you have to include `choiceQuestionSelection` otherwise it would not be loaded

```
_context.Questions.Include(q => q.choiceQuestionSelection).Where(q => q.ExamId == examId);
```

Also, in case `choiceQuestionSelection` is empty, you must initialize it as an empty list to prevent a null reference when you call it.

```
public class Question 
{
    public Question()
    {
        choiceQuestionSelection = new List<choiceQuestionSelection>{};
    }
    public List<ChoiceQuestionSelection> choiceQuestionSelection { get; set; }
}
```